# how to control IP camera AVIDSEN Visia via API

Tags: java, api, ip-camera

I want create a application in java. I want get video stream and picture. I want control this IP camera (left, right, zoom, ...)

I find any API for D-link device but not for AVIDSEN Visia.

I decompile Visia application (APK file) but src code is horrible.

**I find 2 API:**

**image:** http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/tmpfs/auto.jpg

**video+audio:** rtsp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/11 (via VLC for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**flux:**

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/tmpfs/snap.jpg?usr=admin&pwd=password :: Snapshot (720p / 1280x720 Pixel)

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/tmpfs/auto.jpg?usr=admin&pwd=password :: Snapshot (352p or 176p)

rtsp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/11 (via VLC for example) :: video+audio

**Motor:**

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=right :: Moves continuously right

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=left :: Moves continuously left

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=up :: Moves continuously up

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=down :: Moves continuously down

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=stop :: Stops moving camera-head

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=1&-act=right :: Moves one step right

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=1&-act=left :: Moves one step left

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=1&-act=up :: Moves one step up

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=1&-act=down :: Moves one step down

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=home :: Go to Center Position

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=hscan :: Scan horizontal

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/ptzctrl.cgi?-step=0&-act=vscan :: Scan vertical

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/preset.cgi?-act=set&-status=1&-number=[0-7] :: set a position

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/preset.cgi?-act=set&-status=0&-number=[0-7] :: unset a position

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/preset.cgi?-act=goto&-status=1&-number=[0-7] :: goto to a set position

**image:**

brightness :: [0 - 255] the bigger the value the brighter the image

saturation :: [0 - 255] the bigger the value the more saturation the image has

contrast :: [0 - 255] the bigger the value the more contrast the image has

hue :: [0 - 127] the bigger the value the more hue the image has

flip :: (on , off) flips the image

mirror :: (on , off) flips the image

scene :: (auto , indoor , outdoor) sets the white balance mode

**Easy example:** http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setimageattr&-mirror=off

**Complexe example:** http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setimageattr&-brightness=0&-saturation=0&-contrast=0&-hue=0&-flip=off&-mirror=off&-scene=auto

**IR-LED:**

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setinfrared&-infraredstat=auto :: Sets IR LED's to auto mode

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setinfrared&-infraredstat=open :: Sets IR LED's always active :: only IN-6011

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setinfrared&-infraredstat=close :: Sets IR LED's always inactive

**ALARM:**

http://admin:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setmdattr&-enable=1&-name=1 :: enables the md area 1

http://admin:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setmdattr&-enable=0&-name=1 :: disables the md area 1

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/cgi-bin/hi3510/param.cgi?cmd=setioattr&-io_enable=1&-io_flag=1 :: enable / disable external alarm in to trigger recording